# Registration in asp.net core via PhoneNumber instead of Email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, registration

How can I do registration via phone number in Asp.net core instead of Email. In UserManager only exist two method for phone number

```
Task<string> GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(TUser user, string phoneNumber);
Task<bool> VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(TUser user, string token, string phoneNumber)
```

Name of this methods is ambiguous. I can not found any sample in web.

Comment: there is nothing pre-built for that. as far as I know, those methods are for using phone for a second factor in 2 factor auth, so the user would have to already have an account then they can add their phone number and verify it for 2 factor auth. then you also need a service like twilio to send text to the phone to verify it

Comment: tnx for comment. exist any sample implementation of what i want? I can not found any example